# How do I stop a message from being recognized in the bot builder framework

Tags: node.js, botframework

My question is essentially the same as [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/929), but then for the Node version of the BotBuilder framework.

When the bot is added to a channel with multiple users, it will react to every single message, which is not its purpose. I intend to fix this by intercepting the message, and if it contains a mention of the bot, it will be allowed to flow normally, otherwise cancel the action. However I can not find the right function to override. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept messages easily using node SDK. I let you a sample code:

```
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.use({
    botbuilder: function (session, next) {
        myMiddleware.doSthWithIncomingMessage(session, next);
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        myMiddleware.doSthWithOutgoingMessage(event, next);
    }
})

module.exports = {
    doSthWithIncomingMessage: function (session, next) {
        console.log(session.message.text);
        next();
    },
    doSthWithOutgoingMessage: function (event, next) {
        console.log(event.text);
        next();
    }
}
```

Now, every inbound message (from user to bot) will trigger `doSthWithIncomingMessage`, and every outbound message (from bot to user) will trigger `doSthWithOutgoingMessage`. In this example, the bot simply prints some information about each message, but you can modify the behaviour to filter the messages and check about mentions.

Comment: Thanks @gabriel-piffaretti. That's what I was looking for. I am a bit fussy about the exact logic that I should use though.
Basically, I can continue a message with next, but the way I stop the message is currently with session.endDialog. That seems a bit weird, especially if no dialog has taken place yet anyway. Any other suggestions?